# generated MSM file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am trying to create a Windows installer solution with Visual Studio. In the release, it has generated a MSM file which is not recognised by Windows. How can I use that file extention to see the release of the Windows installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct project type for your tool.  .MSM is like LIB/DLL (LIB really) and .MSI is like EXE.  Most tools don't allow you to switch back and forth like a C#/VB.NET project does.  You have to create a new project and select the right type.